# How to align list of abbreviations and symbols with other entries in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms, glossary

I have tried to align the List of Abbreviations and List of symbols with other entries in table of contents using the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0.5in}{1.8in}
\cftsetindents{section}{1in}{1.3in}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{1.5in}{0.8in}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy,toc,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]       {LIST OF SYMBOLS}       {not}       {ntn}       {LIST OF SYMBOLS}
\newglossary[alg]       {LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS} {abb}       {abr}       {LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=40mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \newpage
    \phantomsection
    \tableofcontents
    \phantomsection
    \listoftables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\centering\hspace{3.3cm}\textbf{LIST OF TABLES}}
    %---------------------------------List of figures page--------------------%
    \phantomsection
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\centering\hspace{3.3cm}\textbf{LIST OF FIGURES}}
    %-------------------------------------ABBREVIATIONS page---------------------------%
    \newpage
    \newglossaryentry{LA}{type=LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS, name={LA},description={\hspace*{3.1cm}\textendash\hspace*{3cm}Los Angeles}}
    
    \newglossaryentry{NY} { type=LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS, name={NY},      description={\hspace*{3cm}\textendash\hspace*{3cm}New York City}}
    
    \newglossaryentry{theta}{type= LIST OF SYMBOLS, name={$\theta$}, description={\hspace*{3.1cm}\textendash\hspace*{3cm}The angle of attack},sort={theta}} 
      
    \newglossaryentry{alpha}{type= LIST OF SYMBOLS, name={$\alpha$},
        description={\hspace*{3cm}\textendash\hspace*{3cm}The angle of measurements},sort={alpha}}
    
    \printglossary[type=LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS]
    \newpage
    \printglossary[type= LIST OF SYMBOLS]
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{INTRODUCTION}
    \section{Aim}
    Here are my two abbreviations \gls{LA}  \gls{NY} \gls{alpha} and \gls{theta}.
    \subsection{Introduction}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{For generating nomenclature insert the following string}
        \label{Fig:fig_2}
    \end{figure}
    Table \ref{table:tab1.1} shows format of the table in Latex.
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{Example of Table in Latex}
    \label{table:tab1.1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|p{10cm}|c|}
        \hline
        Figure No. & Caption & Page No. \bigstrut\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    \subsection{Application}
    \section{Activity}
\end{document}
```

The output produced is as follows when compiled:

[image]

What i require is as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Can you reduce your code down into a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please, 220 lines is too many.

Comment: Your code is still too long, we do not require the `glossaries` package and definitions, any of the figure details, any of the tables details (just `\begin{table} \end{table}`, any of the text just `\section{}`, `\chapter{}` etc. **Please read** the link from the earlier comment. Also, what is the issue with your code, the code compiles like your image underneath `TITLE`, what is the purpose of the arrows?